# Is it possible in python to define functions outside of a programs main namespace and add them for easy access like a .h file in c?

Tags: python

I don't want to really define my own PyObject.  I want to have functions available for use within a program, but I don't have a need for class instances and don't want to prefix the function call with the name of the module import.

As an example of what I don't want

```
import coke

coke.make(data)
```

Now an example of what I do want

```
import coke

make(data)
```

Is such possible in Python?

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  This is generally covered right at the beginning.  Can you include a link or the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
from coke import *
make(data)
```

or to import individual functions or classes:

```
from coke import make, make2
```

Comment: Or, `from coke import make` to avoid namespace pollution.

Comment: that works but is kinda sloppy.  I am trying to make a easily usable tool for people to use which just provides a bunch of functions but don't want the functions to be cluttered or to me methods acting on instances.

Comment: So what's wrong with the way Python usually does things? i.e. scoping your functions based on module name. You're right, importing everything into a current namespace is sloppy, but that's what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Let your users do what **they** want to do:

```
import coke
coke.make()
```

or

```
from coke import make
make()
```

or

```
from coke import *
make()
```

You can't stop them, so don't fret about it.